# How do i add a button to a youtube video thumbnail? Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I want to add a button to each thumbnail in youtube, this means the youtube homepage and the relevant videos column. I tried this in my content script but couldn't get it to work.

```
function addButtons()
{
    var overlays = document.querySelectorAll('#overlays');
    overlays.forEach(function(overlay,index) {
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Heyy");
        btn.appendChild(t);
        overlay.appendChild(btn);
    });
}
```

I saw that the divs with the id "overlay" in youtube contained other elements such as the video length and progress graphics so i thought it would be smart to insert the button there, but it did not work.

**Questions:**

**To which element should i "add" the buttons for them to show up on one corner of the thumbnails?**

**Am i adding the buttons the correct way?**

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)

Comment: Does this mean that the snippet above is actually working and i only need to modify before rendering?

Comment: Not sure I follow. I thought the answer I've linked explains it all.

Comment: I edited the post and added questions, im sure that the answer you linked is relevant but i need to be able to do the above first.